# Redirect HTTPS to HTTP with Express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to redirect all https requests to http for a particular domain. I"m a bit new to express and node and wasn't sure where to start. I sort of get basic routing and know that you can require both the http and https methods, but I'm a bit unsure how to combine the methods with the routing. Any ideas? Sorry if this is a newb question.

Comment: Do you have something else in front of node, like nginx or apache? Would surely be easier to use one of those to perform this task.

Comment: Hi Kevin. Nope, just using node and express.

Comment: Then you'll have to open up two listeners, one http listening on port 80 that has all your routes, the other https on port 443 that just redirects all requests with `res.redirect()`

Comment: Ahh, I see. And I'm assuming that I won't need an SSL cert to handle the https request. It's that correct?

Comment: I don't think you will, but i've never done this, so not sure. I've always relied on having something sitting between node and the outside world.

Comment: Great. Thanks Kevin. Much obliged.